# MacBook Pro 2018 - No render devices for OpenCL (2.91.2)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osx, opencl

I am using a 2018 Macbook Pro and I cannot find hwo to setup OpenCL to accelerate my renders.

Is there any way to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled your devices in user preferences? (I know in my image it says "No Compatible GPU's Found - I don't use OpenCL) Your devices should be listed here - Enable them and they should become accessible from the Render Properties menu.

[image: OpenClEnable]